# How to prevent cgroup: fork rejected

Tags: linux, systemd, java

I run a Java application with OpenJDK 8 on Fedora 27, and since some time it logs this from time to time:

```
kernel: cgroup: fork rejected by pids controller in /system.slice/my.service
```

It then also immediately produces:

```
java[22648]: Exception in thread "acme" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

I don't believe the application "leaks" threads. I could be wrong though.

How can I check the system parameters which cause these errors, and how can I modify them to prevent the errors?

**Edit**

The service is run with:

```
java -Xmx1G -jar myservice.jar
```

Comment: Please edit question to show: How are you running the program?

Comment: Use `systemctl cat my.service` to check if there's a pid limitation for the service

Comment: See e.g. https://serverfault.com/questions/628610/increasing-nproc-for-processes-launched-by-systemd-on-centos-7/678861

Comment: Increase TasksMax per service or globally - see https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019044